# Cannot run spring boot application using java -cp command

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to reproduce:

Download the default maven/java spring project from https://start.spring.io/ with spring-web, build it and then I'd like to start it using the following command:

`java -cp target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.demo.DemoApplication`

The error I'm getting is:
`Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.demo.DemoApplication`

I know it works with `java -jar`, but I explicitly want to put more things on the classpath. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a shadow jar plugin instead of the spring-boot one, because spring-boot plugin creates a jar that puts classes in a subfolder, which makes them inaccessible for the `java -cp` command.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming (but it is obvious) that you will be putting jar files in class path.
install the jar file which you want to put in class path using [mvn install](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) like this below

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<complete path here for jar.jar> -DgroupId=com.example.groupId -DartifactId=example-artifact -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Make sure if you have multiple jars to be included in your spring project, you should put different unique groupId, and artifactId, so tha mevn doesn't get confused.

Then add those jars in pom.xml as dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupID from above install command</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact Id from above install command</artifactId>
    <version>version from above install command</version>
</dependency>
```

And then build and run your spring project as you ideally do with

```
java -jar SpringProject.jar
```

Comment: Thats not what I want, I want to dynamically put stuff on the classpath and have the app use it